# giving correct answer in expect script

Tags: remote-access, expect

I want to configure `sensors-detect` automatically and remotely for 10 PC.
The are some 'questions' that need to be answered without my interaction to those PC. These are 5 'questions' and my preferred answer:

```
Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors. 
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no):
```

The answer is `yes`

```
Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no):
```

The answer is `yes`

```
Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no):
```

The answer is `yes`

```
Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no):
```

The answer is `yes`

```
Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no):
```

The answer is `no`

The questions are asked in random manner even the '(yes/no)', some (YES/no) and some (yes/NO) depends on computer type. I've tried to automate this using Expect script:

```
spawn ssh $n2@node2

expect "password:"
send -- "$pa\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "echo $pa | sudo -S apt-get install lm-sensors\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "sudo sensors-detect\r"

expect {
        "I2C/SMBus adapters now?"
        {   send -- "no\r"
            exp_continue
        }
    "Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe."
        {   send -- "yes\r"
            exp_continue
        }
    "Super I/O sensors?"
        {   send -- "yes\r"
            exp_continue
        }
    "IPMI interfaces?"
        {   send -- "yes\r"
            exp_continue
        }
    "I/O ports?"
        {   send -- "yes\r"
            exp_continue
        }
}

expect "Just press ENTER to continue: "
send -- "\r"
expect "Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)"
send -- "yes\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "sudo service kmod start\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Unfortunately, the script wasn't answer it correctly and exit due to timeout. Some question was answered 3 times. This is the error:

```
Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): yes

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): yes

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (yes/NO): yes
yes
yes
yes

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.
no
```

Comment: Whether your code is working fine ? What is the issue you are getting ? With `exp_continue`, the order of occurrence does not matter. By the way, there should be an exit criteria when `exp_continue` used. Give us all the possible questions and your answers so that you can map accordingly. Case sensitive/insensitive is not an issue.

Comment: The script was stuck at the `expect  {` part until timeout. I am not sure how to put exit criteria in the script. `expect "Just press ENTER to continue: "` and afterward occur accordingly as written in the script above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-nocase` to make `Expect` to have case-insensitive pattern matching.

We should not use `-nocase` with uppercase characters in the pattern. Uppercase characters in the pattern can never match.

```
expect -nocase "HI THERE!"  ;# WRONG, CAN NEVER MATCH!
expect -nocase "hi there"   ;# RIGHT!
```

So, your code can altered as,

```
spawn ssh $n2@node2

expect "password:"
send -- "$pa\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "echo $pa | sudo -S apt-get install lm-sensors\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "sudo sensors-detect\r"
expect {
        -nocase "i2c/smbus adapters now?"  {send "no\r";exp_continue}
        -nocase "(yes/no):" {send  "yes\r";exp_continue}
        "Just press ENTER to continue:" {send "\r"}
}
expect "Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)"
send -- "yes\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "sudo service kmod start\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

In your case, when the question `Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now?` comes, then it should be answered as `no`. Rest will be `yes` only. Since `-nocase`  should be passed with lowercase letters, I am using `i2c/smbus adapters now? (yes/no):`.

If this pattern observed, then it will send `no` and in case of other questions, anyway they will be ending with `(yes/no)`, it will send `yes`.

I kept the pattern  `Just press ENTER to continue:` at the end without `exp_continue`, which is our exit criteria from this loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the script led to very long `y`. I realise that if I leave `"Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): "` with no flag, the script will run perfectly. However I just test it on 1 PC. Does the code will be case insensitive if I omit the `-nocase` flag?

Comment: As mentioned, if `-nocase` used, then make sure none of the character in the pattern is in capital letter.

Comment: I able to run the script with a few amendment to the code. I changed the  code to `-nocase "do you want to probe the i2c/smbus adapters now? (yes/no): "` and it work well in all 10 PC. Thank you very much for your help and suggestion.